# VS Code pressing tab does not autocomplete the tag

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am writing JSX tags but I have a problem when I type `div` and press on Tab it does not get completed to `<div></div>`. How I make the tab autocomplete the tag ?

Answer (score 0):

found it. When I change the language to `JavaScript React` it work !!!